# when is !$OMP PARALLEL END DO necessary?

Tags: parallel-processing, fortran, openmp

The OpenMP specification says that the *[!$OMP PARALLEL END DO]* is optional and if not present the compiler assumes it by default. Can I implicitly assume its correctness ? For example

## Version 1: (no end parallel do)

```
do i = 1, N
!$OMP PARALLEL DO DEFAULT(SHARED)
   do j = xadj(i), xadj(i+1) - 1
      call residual(j, ...)
   end do
end do
```

## Version 2: (with end parallel do)

```
do i = 1, N
!$OMP PARALLEL DO DEFAULT(SHARED)
   do j = xadj(i), xadj(i+1) - 1
      call residual(j, ...)
   end do
!$OMP END PARALLEL DO
end do
```

Although the specification says it is optional (safe) how safe is it in practice (for the above example)?

Comment: What did you experience? Is it safe to use?

Comment: @Vogt I am having problems with my MPI + OpenMP code and isolated the problem to the above piece of code in my solver. I am not sure if this is the culprit need to investigate more to confirm.

Comment: @Vogt I also see that all examples provided in the OMP specification always has a !$OMP END PARALLEL DO (except the DO REDUCTION). There is not a single example without it, giving more uncertanity and doubt about its safety.

Comment: I can't think of a case where omitting it will make any difference. But I don't like j being shared in the above, could you show the real code you think is causing the problems?

Comment: @Ian Bush: j is not shared. See OpenMP4.5 standard (the same is in previous versions, but I have 4.5 to hand), p57 line 14 "If any of the loop iteration variables would otherwise be shared, they are implicitly made private on
the loop construct."

Comment: Ahhh, I did wonder about that during my chess match last night ... Thanks.

Comment: @Bush The original code is proprietary, the example I showed is just for illustration purpose, but I concur with Cownie that "j" is private since it is the loop variable. Kindly assume that the contents inside of this subroutine are correctly implemented.